# Show $\mathcal{A}$ is $\sigma$-algebra for $X$ if and only if a statement over increasing sequence holds .

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra for $X \neq \emptyset$. Show $\mathcal{A}$ is $\sigma$-algebra for $X$ if and only if the following statement holds:

$E_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$ and $E_{i} \subset E_{i+1}$ with $i \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$.

I was trying to prove this as follows:

$\Rightarrow$ If $\mathcal{A}$ is $\sigma$ algebra, then  by definition of $\sigma$ algebra we have that for any sequence $\lbrace  E_{i}\rbrace_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $E_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_{i} \in  \mathcal{A}$ particulary if the sequence is increasing as the statement holds. So we are done.

$\Leftarrow$ Having the statement as hypothesis I want to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra. As $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra for $X$ we already have that $X \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under compliments. So, I only need to prove  $\lbrace  E_{i}\rbrace_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $E_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$ is closed under enumerable union.

**Case 1-**  If the sequence is increasing then $\lbrace  E_{i}\rbrace_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $E_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$ is closed under enumerable union as we are supposing the statement.

**Case 2.-** If the sequence is increasing then $\lbrace  E_{i}\rbrace_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $E_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$ is decreasing.

**Case 3.-** If the sequence is is such $\lbrace  E_{i}\rbrace_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $E_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$ is such is neither increasing or decreasing.

If my idea of proving this by cases how can I end up this proof as Im pretty up out of ideas to prove case 2 and case 3.

Other ways to prove this are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Having any sequence $\{E_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$, we can form a sequence $\{F_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$, where $F_i = \bigcup_{j=1}^i E_i$. Note that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty F_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$, and $F_i \subset F_{i+1}$ for every $i \in \mathbb N$

Comment: Nice hint! Let me try your idea a few minutes and see If can end up the proof. Any gap in the other implication of my proof? @DominikKutek

Comment: I don't understand case 2, but "=>" is correct and as you noticed all you need to do for "<=" is to show that for any sequence $\{E_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ we have $\bigcup E_i \in \mathcal A$, so everything seems correct to me.

Comment: Thanks!! The equality of unions you mentioned can be proved  straightforward  by two element contentions without problem.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E_n, n \in \omega$ is any sequence in the algebra $\mathcal{A}$, define $$E'_n = \bigcup_{i \le n} E_i \in \mathcal{A}$$

as algebras are closed under finite unions. Also the sequence $E'_n$ is increasing in $n$ by definition, and it's easy to check that

$$\bigcup_n E_n = \bigcup_n E'_n \in \mathcal{A}$$

the last holding by the assumption on the increasing sequences of sets.  No need for case distinctions.